# Encrypted in Node using AES/CBC/NOPADDING and decrypted in JAVA using same algorithm gives some junk like e�J�,�d�|*�5Ҝ��

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I have to decrypt some text which is encrypted in Node using AES/CBC/NOPADDING algorithm but end up getting some garbage value when decrypted in JAVA .. Please help...

Node Encryption code:

```
const iv = "0123456789012345";
ALGORITHM : 'aes-256-cbc',
ACCESS_CODE : MD5('Imgine#123$')

function encrypt(text) {
 var cipher      = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
 var encrypted   = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "base64");
 encrypted       += cipher.final("base64"); // to hex

 return encrypted;
}
```

Java Decryption code:

```
private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    public static String decrypt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        String base64Cipher = "t7rCN8nBGlruCiSvpQ9DPg==";
        byte [] iv = "0123456789012345".getBytes(UTF8);
        byte [] secretBytes = "Imgine#123$".getBytes(UTF8);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(secretBytes);

        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Cipher))) ;
   }
```

Result: `e�J�,�d�|*�5Ҝ��`

Comment: What happens when you do: `new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Cipher)), "UTF-8")`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the same result result - e�J�,�d�|*�5Ҝ��

Comment: JavaScript uses UTF-16 or UCS-2 for character encoding, but in Java you are reducing your strings to UTF-8.

Comment: But in JS side also UTF-8 only used for character encoding, that is why am also using the same in JAVA.

Comment: You are not always using UTF-8 in JS, your MD5 and other key creation variables are still relying on UTF-16 or UCS-2.

Comment: Tried UTF - 16, but the result is same.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. You don't show how the key is generated on the Node side, but you appear to be using AES-256. However, on the Java side you are using AES-128 because your key is 16 bytes.

Comment: Key is static, not generated dynamically

Comment: That doesn't matter - you can't use 128 bits of key data with AES-256, by definition.  I also don't see anywhere in your Node code that you specify no padding.  I'm pretty sure Node uses PKCS#7 padding by default.  I suggest you fix up the issues outlined by myself and others and modify the code in your question.

Comment: Quite often idiotic implementations of MD5 output hexadecimals rather than binary by default. Then you'll have your 256 bits (with only 128 bits of entropy max, but yeah).

Answer (score -2):

Eventually, I found the root cause, the culprit is converting key to MD5 which doesn't convert as required, the MessageDigest is converting the key to 128 bit, it has to be 256, am using the below method to convert the key as required which worked for me, Thanks for all your valuable inputs.

```
public static String getMd5(String input)
{
    try {

        // Static getInstance method is called with hashing MD5
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        // digest() method is called to calculate message digest
        //  of an input digest() return array of byte
        byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());

        // Convert byte array into signum representation
        BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

        // Convert message digest into hex value
        String hashtext = no.toString(16);
        while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
            hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
        }
        return hashtext;
    }

    // For specifying wrong message digest algorithms
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be warned that hacking crypto usually doesn't result in secure code. As you're already confusing passwords and keys, presume that no adequate security can be found anywhere in this Q/A. I've downvoted as you mainly used my comment as answer, without explaining what you are actually doing or indicating that it is not secure.